# mapGetters function behaves differently from store.getters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

as you can see below I have a getter which returns a new method which takes a parameter, according to the documentation I should be able to call this method without doing two method calls. This works great if I use the store.getters directly, however I want to use mapGetters, but in order to get a value and not just the returned function. I need to call the method 'twice' as you would expect in vanilla js. Am I doing something wrong or is this an edge case?

Thanks

```
export default {
    components: { AddRemove, NumberInput },
    methods: {
        ...mapGetters({getExtra: types.GET_EXTRA}),

        // Why can I omit the parenthesis when using the store.getters directly?
        extraAmountWithoutParenthesis(code) {
            return this.$store.getters.getExtra(code)   // returns integer      
        },

        // And why do I require them when using a named mapGetters method
        extraAmountRequiresParenthesis(code) {
            // return this.getExtra(code)  // returns function
            return this.getExtra()(code)   // returns integer
        }
    }
}
```

In my getters:

```
[types.GET_EXTRA]: (state) => (code) => {
        let value = state.extras[code]
        if (!value) {
            value = 0
        }
        return parseInt(value)
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapGetters()` result must be merged into `computed`, not `methods`.

Comment: Ah, it was that simple.. Thanks!